# callback function (arrow) and class method in TimeOut

Tags: javascript, callback, settimeout

I want to trigger 2 functions with a unique timeOut.
The following works fine

```js
    setTimeout(function() {
      function1(); // runs first
      function2(); // runs second
    }, 1000)
```

But in my case, I have a class method and an callback (arrow function).
It looks like this (minimalized):

```js
    class Timer {
      constructor(callback) {
        this.active = false;
        this.callback = callback;
      }

      cancel() {
        this.active = false;
      }

      set() {
        this.active = true;
        this.timeOut = setTimeout( function() {
          this.cancel();
          this.callback; // HERE is my problem. doesn't run, not casted as a function
        }, 1000)
      }
```

I get the following error `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`.
Any trick to fix that?

Comment: just call the callback function `this.callback()`

Comment: then I get `TypeError: this.callback is not a function`

Comment: the problem was I didn't call it right way: arrow function callback should be called with `() => {` and not with `function() {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling callback function, you can also add type check before calling.

```
set() {
  this.active = true;
  this.timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
    this.cancel();
    typeof this.callback === 'function' && this.callback();
  }, 1000)
}
```